# Prepopulate a dropdown menu with multiple options from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Newbie here... I tried to adapt my code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125091/how-to-make-currently-selected-drop-down-menu-item-be-preselected-from-database#_=_)

The list is populated properly but I can't get it to pre-select. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
$q = "SELECT cat_id FROM category_user WHERE cat_id=$d";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
            $cat = (int)$row['cat_id'];
        }
        $q = "SELECT cat_id, cat FROM category";        
        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r)> 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\"";
                $selected = '';
                $cid=(int)$row[0];
                if ($cid=$cat) {
                    $selected='selected="selected"';
                    echo $selected;
                echo ">$row[1]</option>\n";
                }else{


                //Check for stickyness
                if (isset($_POST['category'])&&($_POST['category']== $row[0])) 
                echo 'selected="selected"';
                echo ">$row[1]</option>\n";
            }
            }
        }

 category
 ---------------
 |cat_id | cat  |
 ---------------


 category_user
 -------------------------
 |cu_id | user_id | cat_id|
 -------------------------
```

Comment: your first query is returning the cat_id when you supply it a cat_id... so you can remove that. What is it supposed to be pre-populated to? Something from the database or something sent via $_POST?

Comment: woops! I made a boo-boo in the first query. the table should have read "category_user" as I am matching numbers from two tables. Sorry I'm a dork.

Comment: OK, i see your edit, but your column must be wrong in either the select or the where clause of your first query. Even if using a different table you are retrieving the same column that you specify in your where clause... `cat_id`

Comment: The select statement works in MYSQL. category_user.cat_id is a foreign key for category.cat_id, if that helps at all (I'm not very good at explaining, sorry again). I tried changing array to assoc, in the while clause, but nothing seemed to change.

Comment: Do I need to use foreach in the while clause since I'm calling an array?

Comment: can you provide some sample table structure for `category_user` and `category`. Again I think that your first query is your problem. as you think it is necessary, but in the way you have it, it is not. I think we all might be missing some data here. Can you try to explain what you are trying to accomplish with your first query in more detail. Where does `$cat_id` come from and how is it different than `$cat`?

Comment: category table has columns "cat_id", "cat":  category_user has "cu_id", "user", and "cat_id". $cat_id is a $_post from a previous page. I'll change that to $d for clarification (too many cats!)

Comment: Thanks but can you still try to explain what you are trying to accomplish with your first query in more detail. you are using cat_id in the where clause and then retrieving cat_id in the select clause. if they are the same why not just do `$cat=$d` if you expect the `$cat` to be different then the `$d` then please explain. I think that in place of the `cat_id` in your where clause of your first query, you want either `cu_id` or `user_id`

Comment: category is a stable list of categories that never changes. The drop down list is populated from this table. Category_user combines the category table and the user table, so the foreign key (cat_id) in this list has the items that need to be pre-selected in the menu.

Comment: again, do you expect `$cat` to be different from `$d`? Yes or No?

Comment: yes. Thank you for being so patient.

Comment: OK, so if `$d` is the `cat_id` in the where clause and `$cat` is the value set from `cat_id` in the select clause, and `cat_id==cat_id`, then how do you expect them to ever return differently. they cannot be the same and different at the same time.

Comment: $d is not the cat_id in the where clause. I was using too many similar names for different things and $d is an id from an entirely different table. you can ignore it.

Comment: so is this answered and working, or are you still having problems with it?

Comment: yes I figured it out. Thanks for your help. I'm just waiting for the 24 hour "accept your own answer" period to expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. the foreach loop preselects everything for the dropdown menu. The problems were mostly getting the array from the mysql table to iterate as selected. The last piece of the puzzle were the brackets [] after $cats.

Thanks for your help, and sorry I wasn't very clear on what I was trying to accomplish. My bad.

```
<p><select class=\"box\" name=\"wkType[]\" multiple=\"multiple\">";
$q = "SELECT cat_id FROM category_user WHERE user_id=$d";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    $cats[]=$row['cat_id'];                     
}
    $q = "SELECT cat_id, cat FROM category";        
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r)> 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\"";
            foreach ($cats as $key =>$cat) {
        if ($row[0]==$cat){
        echo 'selected="selected"';
                    //Check for stickyness
        if (isset($_POST['category'])&&($_POST['category']== $row[0])) 
            echo 'selected="selected"';
        }
                  }
        echo ">$row[1]</option>\n";
          }
}else{
echo '<p>Please select a category.</p>';    
}   
echo "</select></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why overcomplicate the code. You can try something like this

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT cat_id, cat FROM category");
    if ($result) {
        echo "<select name='whatever_you_want'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='{$row[0]}'";
            if (intval($row[0]) == intval($cat_id)) {
                echo " selected";
            }
            echo ">{$row[1]}</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I did think it was too complicated, but I have to match ids from two tables to get a multiple preselect. So how do I do that?

Comment: (just realized I made a mistake and put the wrong table in the first query. Fixed it! Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

```
if($cid=$cat){
```

should be

```
if($cid==$cat){
```

and

```
$cid=(int)$row[0];
```

`(int)` is unnecessary because string to int are compared automatically.

Comment: @artsyL just make sure that you use `==` and not `===` as that will compare not only value but also type. For instance `'2'==2 && 2===2` would result in true but `'2'===2` will result in false. And only one `=` sets the value and most of the time is not what you want to be doing.